# Curvilinear regression non-significant t test but significant F test

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, t-test, interpretation

I conducted a curvilinear regression predicting personality scores from just one predictor variable (autism traits). The t test came out as non-significant, although the F test came out as significant. Could anyone explain what this means?

Comment: My understanding is that Fisher originally created the "F-test" for comparing different models, and is a relative score used in model selection. Can anyone more knowledgable than I weigh in on the practical use of this statistic?

Comment: To get a useful answer you will likely have to provide: 1) what software you are using; 2) what model you are using; 3) and the actual output you are looking at.